# Jest: why does it fail with SyntaxError: Unexpected token . for css class?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I wrote a React application and used jest to write unit tests.

when I run it by "jest --config=jest.config.json --watch" I get the following error:

Test suite failed to run

> ```
> /home/user/Projects/react-game/src/Square.css:1
> ({"Object.>
> ```
>
> ":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){.bluePawn,
>   .blueMasterPawn, .redPawn, .redMasterPawn {
>                                                                                                ^
>       SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
>
> ```
>   at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/ScriptTransformer.js:289:17)
>   at Object.<anonymous> (src/MasterPawn.js:3:1)
>   at Object.<anonymous> (src/Utils.js:3:19)
> ```

I just want to note that compiler marks ".bluePawn" which is a class name. Therefore, I understand that it cannot read class name.

It looks like something that has to do with configurations.
I was searching on the web, and didn't find any solution that could help me.

Comment: Are you importing any `css` files inside your components?

Comment: yes. css files are imported to my components

Answer (score 1):

Create an empty css file named `stub.css` inside `src`.

Then add this to your `package.json` :

```
"jest": {
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      ".*css$": "<rootDir>/src/stub.css",
    },
```

Comment: thanks, but now I see that the error has changed: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50144229/jest-why-does-it-fail-with-typeerror-path-must-be-a-string-received-undefined

Comment: It looks like an error related to the tests themselves, and not the config of `jest`